# pymongo update/insert a dict in a document

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymongo

I want to insert a dict into a document as the value for a field (say `v`) if this document does not exist;

```
db.table.update_one({'k': some_unique_key},
                    {'$set': {'v': {name: 'some_name'},
                    upsert=True)
```

Also if the document exists, I want to update the document by updating the dict of the same field (`v`), i.e. adding one `name: value` pair to `v`, I am wondering how to do that.

e.g. the original document is like,

```
{'k': some_key, 'v': {'name_a': 'name_a_val'}}
```

adding one more key:value pair `name_b:name_b_val` to `v` is like

```
{'k': some_key, 'v': {'name_a': 'name_a_val', 'name_b': 'name_b_val'}}
```

UPDATE

this is the solution I came up with

```
if not db.table.find_one({'k': some_unique_key}):
    db.table.insert_one({'k': some_unique_key, 'v': {'name_a': 'name_a_val'})
else:
    v_val_dict = db.table.find_one({'k': some_unique_key})['v']

    vat_cache.update_one({'k': some_unique_key},
                     {'$set': {'v': v_val_dict.update({'name_b': 'name_b_val'})}})
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: @thanasisp does it look better now

Answer (score 3):

you have to use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#embedded-documents). This will update the nested field named `name_a` or will create it inside `v` if it doesn't exist.

```
coll.update_one({'k': 'some_key'}, 
                {'$set': { 'v.name_a': 'name_a_val'}}, upsert=True)
```

Comment: should it be `coll.update_one({'k': 'some_key'}, 
                {'$set': { 'v'.'name_a': 'name_a_val'}}, upsert=True)`?

Comment: tried it with `coll.update_one({'k': 'some_key'}, 
                {'$set': { v.'name_a': 'name_a_val'}}, upsert=True)`, got error `name 'v' is not defined` when `'some_key'` doesn't exist